# How to dynamically change a list value to another list in Java or Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

For Example, I have a list like below,

`list1 = ["a","b","c"] now i want to add value to the list[1] index and that index` will be another list like,

list2 = ["w","x","y"]

The output will be ["a",["b","w","x","y"],"c"] I don't want to replace 1 index

Is it possible?

Comment: What about `list1.set(1, ["b","x","y"])`?

Comment: 1 index will be change at run time, like when i will run the program another element will insert that index automatically. And also i don't know the value of 1th index

Comment: or even like this: `list1[1] = ["b","x","y"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base list contains two types: `String` and `List<String>`

You can create a list as your base list in java but is not a good idea because you are mixing types. That is a bad practice. You should [avoid raw types](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=224).

You could use a helper method like :

```
private static List mergeIntoList(List source, List listToAdd, int index) {
    List innerList = new ArrayList(listToAdd);
    innerList.add(0, source.get(index));

    List mergedList = new ArrayList(source);
    mergedList.set(index, innerList);

    return mergedList;
}
```

Exemple:

```
 List source = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
 List listToAdd = Arrays.asList("w", "x", "y");

 System.out.println(mergeIntoList(source, listToAdd, 1));
```

output: [a, [b, w, x, y], c]

**But I repeat, you should avoid raw types, so this solution is not recommended**

Comment: def newList = []
newList.add("D")
def list1 = ["a","B","C"]
list1.set(1,newList)
println(list1)  // Actually when i set a new list at 1th index it is replacing the 1th index value but i want that value also. And it is actually groovy problem

Comment: @masudbappy i updated my answer because you change your question

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but not very type safe (=***don't do it***). You could use a List and then add your values, which could be any type of Object (Integer String... or another List).
When retrieving the Objects you would need to check what type they are with instanceof and then cast them.

Comment: Actually i am using groovy and so far groovy is type safe.

Answer (score 0):

In java it is not possible taking type of list1 as `String`.
Type of list1 seems String and you are adding another list into list1 which is not correct.

But it is possible taking type list1 as `Object`

```
List<Object> list1=new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("a");
list1.add("b");
list1.add("c");

List<Object> innerlist=new ArrayList<>();  //Inner List

list1.add(innerlist);
```

**However it is not recommended way.**

Answer (score 0):

You can add value to a specific index as below

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    List l1 = new ArrayList();
    l1.add("3");
    l1.add("4");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("5");
    list.add(1, l1);
```

Please make sure that index in the list size, otherwise will get the **IndexOutOfBoundsException**

Please try below logic

```
public List replaceIndex(List original, List replace, int index) {
    Object object = original.remove(index);
    replace.add(0, object);
    original.add(index, replace);
    return original;
}
```

Comment: def newList = []
newList.add("D")
def list1 = ["a","B","C"]
list1.set(1,newList)
println(list1)  // Actually when i set a new list at 1th index it is replacing the 1th index value but i want that value also. And it is actually groovy problem

Comment: @masudbappy Seems you have to write a small logic to fulfill your requirement. I'll update the answer.